# c++ file read/write infinite loop that rewrites the txt again

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to learn how to use file handling in C++.
I'd like to save and edit the contents of variables, however, there seems to be a problem with my logic because somehow the following program re writes the contents of the file infinitely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *filePointer = fopen("text.txt", "r+");
    char currentChar;
    int loop = 0;
    currentChar = getc(filePointer);
    while (currentChar != EOF && loop < 100)
    {
        if (currentChar == '=')
        {
            fseek(filePointer, 1, 1);
            if (fputs("LOL", filePointer) == EOF)
            {
                return 2;
            }
            
        }
        
        std::cout << ftell(filePointer) << "Current Char: " << currentChar << std::endl;
        currentChar = getc(filePointer);
        
        loop++;
    }
    fclose(filePointer);
    return 0;
}
```

The code that the program reads is the following:

"
hello = \n
yay!
"

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is exactly what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn run your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logic and execution. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. We don't debug other people's code on Stackoverflow, but with your debugger's help you can find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without needing any help.

Comment: i'll try it out, thanks for the advice

Comment: Taking a step back, I suspect you assume that your `fputs` call would insert three characters `LOL` in the middle of the file. It does not; rather, it **overwrites** three characters at the current file position. In your example, I believe it'll write over `\n y`, ending up with `hello = LOLay!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program exhibits undefined behavior. From C99 standard (which governs C standard library functions and is incorporated into the C++ standard by reference):

> **7.19.5.3/6** When a file is opened with update mode (`'+'` as the second or third character in the above list of `mode` argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

You have output (`fputs`) immediately followed by input (`getc`) without an intervening `fflush` or a file positioning function.

Answer (score 0):

Text is stored contiguously on disk, and just like arrays, if you want to insert it, you must move the original element back, otherwise the effect of the execution is an overlay